# Why are "is equal to" and "total strict ordering" mutually exclusive?

Tags: relations, order-theory

Let $A$ be a set. Let $=$ be the relation "is equal to" on $A{\times}A$, and let $<$ be a strict total ordering on $A{\times}A$. How do we prove that if $a<b$, then it's not true that $a=b$?

Comment: By definition of strict total ordering. A strict order relation is anti-symmetric.

Comment: @geodude Don't you mean *antireflexive*?

Comment: @GitGud Oh yes, sorry. Not enough coffee this morning!

Comment: @geodude You're still in time to edit the comment, I believe. **Edit:** Not anymore. If you delete your comments,I'll delete mine and you can repost as you see fit.